# References and books

Tags: reference-request

I am a post graduate student and want to strengthen my base in mathematics. So please suggest me reference books about the following subjects, from which I clear my doubts and gain a lot of knowledge. The subjects are

1. Real analysis
2. Linear algebra
3. Abstract algebra
4. Complex analysis
5. Differential equations
6. Partial differential equations
7. Topology
8. Metric space
9. Set theory

Comment: It might help if you mention any previous experience you have had with the topics; and additional background - like what graduate program you are currently pursuing. Excessive rigor is probably the last thing you want.

Comment: I have to clear my basic concepts . so want to read best references books.... So i need suggestions

Comment: Plese give me suggestions... I really need it

Comment: I'am not familiar with most of the topics but I can tell you it will take you months of full time effort to cover all the fundamentals of these topics; anways, here goes: 1] "Intro to Real analysis - Bartle and Sherbert"(There are better ones but I haven't used them. - perhaps one of Rudin's books.)  2] "Intro to Linear Algebra - Gilbert Strang" - (There are MIT OCW lectures to supplement the book if required.) 9] Pick the sections you want from "Naive Set Theory - Paul Halmos"

Comment: As an expository text you can try: "All the Mathematics You Missed
But Need to Know for Graduate School - Thomas Garrity"

Comment: Thanks Akay   i also read real analysis bartle... Excellent book till now for me.......and thanks for other suggestions...

Comment: Thanks a lot akay  now recently i download  book "All the Mathematics You Missed
But Need to Know for Graduate School - Thomas Garrity", it  is great i read only  one page.and  it tells me that why i study mathematics. It is great. I am thankful to you for whole of my life...........